# MultiCasting using UDP in C++

Tags: c++

I want to develop one client server App using Multicasting using UDP in c++
Any code snippet or ideas...
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have any library in mind? It will vary depending on the library used. (Using a library is most likely preferable to dealing with sockets directly).

Comment: I dont have any idea can u tell me more on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other possibility in my mind: [Windsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741394%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using ASIO? http://think-async.com/

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).